# Variance service times M/G/c queue

Tags: variance, queueing-theory

I am wondering about the influence of the variance of the service times in an M/G/c queue on the probability that a customer has to wait. Intuitively, I would say that smaller variance implies smaller waiting probability, but I can not think of a sound reasoning. Could you help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would depend of what kind of distribution is for service time. For example, for exponential or poisson distribution, larger variance means larger mean service time. Therefore, there is bigger potential for the customers have to wait.